# AppSync WebSocket connection life cycle

Tags: aws-appsync

I am building an app with Socket.io, which allows to keep constant communication between clients and the server. I recently discovered AppSync, but I don't know if the WebSocket connection will die after an hour (AWS limits the WebSocket connection to 1 hr in other services). I checked the documentation for AppSync, but I do not see anything about this. Does it also handle automatic reconnection? Is it possible to detect when a webSocket disconnection has occured?

Answer (score 1):

which platform are you targeting? JS/iOS/Android? There are respective client libraries which will help you interact with AppSync and manage automatic reconnection.

iOS https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios

Android https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android

JS https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js

General documentation for the AWS frameworks https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/

If you need further information about them, I'd suggest taking a look at the links above, taking a look at the Issues or opening one with the respective repo's with any questions.

Hope that helps!